# Java keeping highest number

Tags: java

```
int number = 0;
    int score = 0;



    while (true) {

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter mark :");
        number = input.nextInt(); 


        Scanner mark=new Scanner(System.in);
        score = mark.nextInt();

         if (number > score ) {
             System.out.println("Highest mark:" + number);
         }

        else if (number > 100) {
            System.out.println("Invalid enter number 0-100");
         }

        else if
            (number < 0){


            System.out.println("Invalid enter number 0-100");

            if(input.equals("quit")){
                break;
```

Greetings, I would like to know how to keep the highest mark and the lowest mark after the student enters the number. and only to allow to enter numbers between 0-100. Thank you

Comment: You know how to compare values, you know how to declare variables, you know how to assign values, what's keeping you from doing what you want to do?

Comment: My mind, I actually cant think how to do it. Will you please help me and guide me to the right direction.

Comment: If you're able to write the code that you posted, I seriously don't understand what you're struggling with right now. Except of course, that's not your code, but then I wonder who wrote it and why are you posting it?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Don't create new `Scanner` objects all the time. Create one `Scanner` object outside the loop.

Comment: It seems that `score` contains the current "highest mark", so when you find a new "highest mark", don't you think you need to update `score` to that value?

Comment: @max vollmer well it is my code and if you actually tried to run it you could see that its not doing what I want it to do.

Comment: *FYI:* `input.equals("quit")` will never be true, because a `Scanner` object is never equal to a `String` object.

Comment: Andreas, thank you a lot I try to fix it now. how should I update the score value?

Comment: If you truly did write that code, then you should have already learned about the *assignment* statement. Perhaps you should (re)read your Java training material.

Comment: @Andreas Using one scanner worked very well thank you

Comment: You know `int something;`, you know `if (something > somethingElse)` and you know `something = somethingElse;`. You know what each of these do. You have the desired behavior "if something is bigger than something else store something". So, I really, really don't understand why you don't just write exactly that down in your code.

Comment: The code now works it shows me the highest and the lowest mark.

Comment: We are at a point where the solution is so obvious, that the only thing we could do is give you finished code. But I'd rather have you figure that out yourself, because that's how you learn.

Comment: Well im in my first year in uni doing computer science im still very new to Java.

Comment: Youre right @MaxVollmer I understand you

Comment: But thinking for 2 hours where you went wrong and what goes where is too much for me :-D

Comment: I can only admire the people who know so many programming languages and point out obvious mistakes straight away. Hopefully that will be me in next few years.

Comment: You are on the right track I am sure!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two variables to keep track of the highest and lowest marks. Since you want your marks to be between 0 and 100, you can give starting values of the two variables -1 and 101 respectively:

```
int max = -1;
int min = 101;
```

> `-1` is not a reachable value and is lower than all the reachable values so any value in the given range is bigger than it which makes it perfect for a starting value for the `max` variable. If it starts from 101, no value in the range is bigger so the variable won't change. If the variable is 50 for exmaple, the values in the range 0-50 aren't bigger than 50 and they will be missed. The same logic can be done to see why I chose the value of `101` for the `min` variable.

---

Now you can enter marks and keep track of the highest and lowest one:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(system.in);
while (true) {
    int mark = sc.nextInt();
    if (mark > max) {
        max = mark;
    }
    if (mark < min) {
        min = mark;
    }
}
```

Now the highest and lowest marks will be kept in the `max` and `min` variables respectively.

---

To implement the exit logic you can have the user to input a value outside the range and this will exit from the loop:

```
if (mark < 0 || mark > 100) {
    break;
}
```

This if statement has to be put before the checking for highest and lowest mark because you don't mant to keep trak of such values.

---

This is the final code:

```
int max = -1;
int min = 101;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a value between 0 and 100. If the number is outside this range, the entering will stop.");
    int mark = sc.nextInt();

    //Exit logic
    if (mark < 0 || mark > 100) {
        //Closing the Scanner object (Not necessary but recommended)
        sc.close();
        break;
    }

    //Comapring
    if (mark > max) {
        max = mark;
    }
    if (mark < min) {
        min = mark;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the score you just need to update your score.

```
if (number > score ) {
             score = number;          //update your score
             System.out.println("Highest mark:" + number);
         }
```

You should be able to solve this yourself tho.